# Printing prime numbers in Assembly

Tags: primes, assembly

I am learning to code in the Assembly language for the x86 architecture. I currently know of a few registers and certain arithmetic operations like add, sub, inc, dec, mov and to check for conditionality using certain jump statements. I am using some "ready-baked" code for input and output. The input - `call_hex` reads hex from the input and stores it in the eax register and the output - `print_eax` just prints whatever is in the eax. I am no programmer per se, my end goal is to understand enough assembly to start picking up other things like exploit development. The code below is an exercise to print prime numbers. I know the code I have below could look downright ugly. But if you were rating the code, how much would I get on a scale of 1 to 10, 10 being the highest.

```
; A prime number is an integer that is divisible only by 1 and by itself.
; A program that takes a number n as input, and prints back to the console all the    primes that are larger than 1 but not larger than n.

format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc' 

; ===============================================
section '.text' code readable executable

start:
    ; Your program begins here:

    ; Division Operations - 
    ;eax <- edx:eax/arg
    ;edx <- edx:eax % arg

    call    read_hex

lb2:    
    dec     eax
    jz      exit
    jmp     prime_check

prime_check:

    ; The check for whether 2 is a prime is done separately here
    mov     ecx, eax
    sub     ecx, 2
    jz      is_prime

    mov     ecx, eax        ; eax will be overwritten, hence need to store it someplace else to recover it
    mov     edx, 0          ; initialing the edx:eax registers
    mov     ebx, 2

lb1:
    dec     eax             ; The 3 lines of code are there cause I need a way to exit the program, when eax inside this block is 1.
    jz      exit            ; This seems to be an easy fix. Although downright inelegant
    inc     eax
    div     ebx             
    mov     eax, ecx
    sub     edx, 1
    jc      lb2             ; The case where number isnt prime
    mov     eax, ecx        ; re-initialing the edx:eax registers
    mov     edx, 0          ; re-initialing the edx:eax registers
    inc     ebx
    sub     ecx, ebx
    jz      is_prime
    mov     ecx, eax    
    jmp     lb1

is_prime:
    call    print_eax
    jmp     lb2

exit:
    ; Exit the process:
    push    0
    call    [ExitProcess]

include 'training.inc'
```

Comment: *"how much would I get on a scale of 1 to 10, 10 being the highest."* -- We don't rate code around here. We make it better ;-)

Comment: *The check for whether 2 is a prime is done separately here* - what do you mean?  2 is a prime.

Comment: @Jamal Its just checking to see if the number in the eax register is 2 or something else. If it's something else, I do the prime test elsewhere. If it's 2 I don't do any more tests on it.

Comment: Oh, okay.  That comment sounded a bit misleading.

Comment: @janos Ok. So would you say the code is okay or can it be vastly improved.

Answer (score 2):

This code can be much improved.

The `jmp prime_check` is superfluous.

The comment **; The check for whether 2 is a prime is done separately here** is wrong because it actually jumps to *is_prime* when **n=3** due to the `dec eax` used at *lb2*. 
Also checking for 2 is usually done with `cmp eax,2` and `je is_prime`.

If you cleared EDX (with `xor edx,edx`) after *lb1:* you wouln't have to write it 2 times.

Why don't you replace that **downright inelegant** code with `cmp eax,1` and `je exit`?

The usual way to test if EDX is zero is to use `test edx,edx` and `jz lb2`.